# How to install ROM when bootloader is not unlocked?

Tags: bootloader, htc, bootloader-lock

Accidentally, on stock recovery, I selected `wipe data/factory reset` which could have uninstalled the ROM on it. So, now my mobile is showing company logo only.

My mobile `HTC Inspire A9192`'s bootloader has not been unlocked yet.

How to boot the mobile again ?

Every time I restart my phone, the data/ cache and system gets unmounted.

Answer (score 1):

A factory reset doesn't wipe the ROM files, only the user data, so you can't have "uninstalled the ROM" that way.

Having a locked bootloader doesn't stop you flashing a ROM: it just limits you to official ROMs signed by the manufacturer (or possibly by the carrier). So even if you can't or don't want to unlock the bootloader, you can still flash the stock ROM in the usual way from the recovery, if you can obtain a backup of it.

Comment: there is already something like clockworkmod named HTC ACE and its on chinese. While I tried to flash clockworkmod, it returned error that remote is not allowed.

And I don't know why the mobile is keep showing the HTC logo, I felt like its taking time for first boot but it kept showing for more than 30 mins. any solution ?

Comment: Every time I restart my phone, the data/ cache and system gets unmounted. :(